# Find conditional expectation of $\mathbb{E}(\frac{X}{Y}|X-Y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, conditional-expectation

Consider $X : p_{X}(x) = \frac{1}{x}\mathbb{1}_{(1,e)}$ and $Y : p_{Y}(x) = 4x^{3}\mathbb{1}(x\in (0,1))$.

We want to find conditional expectation of $\mathbb{E}(\frac{X}{Y}|X-Y)$

My attempt :

$p_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{4y^3}{x}\mathbb{1}(1\le x \le e) \mathbb{1}(0\le y\le1)$

So, consider for some $B \in $ *B*(R) :

$\displaystyle \int_{(X/Y|X-Y) \in B} \frac{4y^{3}}{x}\mathbb{1}(1 \le x\le e) \mathbb{1}(0 \le y \le 1)$, after substitution $x/y = t, x-y = z$ we have $\mathbb{J} = \frac{z}{(1-t)^{2}}$ and so $\displaystyle \int_{(t,z)\in B} \frac{4(t-1)(t-1)^{3}z}{tz(t-1)^2}\mathbb{1}(1 \le \frac{zt}{t-1}\le e) \mathbb{1}(0 \le \frac{z}{t-1} \le 1) = \int_{B} \frac{4(t-1)^2}{tz^3}\mathbb{1}(1 \le \frac{zt}{t-1}\le e) \mathbb{1}(0 \le \frac{z}{t-1} \le 1) dt dz, $

so $p_{(X/Y,X-Y)}(t,z) = \frac{4(t-1)^2}{tz^3}\mathbb{1}(1 \le \frac{zt}{t-1}\le e) \mathbb{1}(0 \le \frac{z}{t-1} \le 1)$

Now we want to find $\displaystyle p_{z} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{4(t-1)^2}{tz^3}\mathbb{1}(1 \le \frac{zt}{t-1}\le e) \mathbb{1}(0 \le \frac{z}{t-1} \le 1) dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{4}{(wz)^{3}(1+w)}\mathbb{1}(1-z\le wz \le e-z)\mathbb{1}(0\le wz\le 1) dw$

There is a first problem : how can I find this integral? I should consider different values of $z$? Am i right ? Any HINTS, cause I have a lot of misunderstandings here.

Comment: What is the extra $1$ in $p_X(x)=\frac{1}{x} 1$ for? If it were just $\frac{1}{x}$ its integral over $(1,e)$ would be $1$ as required.

Comment: @for determine the $supp$ of r.v. I guess.

Comment: But it's clear support is the interval $(1,e).$ Or is it really $1_{(1,e)},$ the indicator function of interval $(1,e)$...

Comment: @coffeemath yes this indicator as a function

Comment: So you are given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I am writing this as an answer.  Your join density expression is only correct if $X, Y$ are independent.  Is this the case?

Otherwise note that
$$ \mathbb E \left( \left. {X\over Y} \right| X - Y = a \right) = 1 + \mathbb E \left( \left. {a\over Y} \right| X - Y = a \right) $$

Maybe this can help?